# Трабл в рабочем коде

Tags: python

Код работает, в 17 строке сделал чтобы на месте пропущенных букв было `_`, но не показывает. Потом при вводе букв для слова программа рано показывает верное слово и еще есть 2 попытки для ввода.

```
import random

def hangman():
print('Добро пожаловать в игру Виселица')

wordlist = ['красный', 'синий', 'черный', 'белый', 'серый', 'фиолетовый', 'оранжевый', ]
secret = random.choice(wordlist)
vowels = 'аиеёоуыэюя'
turns = 5

while turns > 0:
    missed = 0
    for letter in secret:
        if letter in vowels:
            print(letter,end=' ')
        else:
            print('_',end='')
            missed += 1
            
        if missed == 0:
            print('\nТы победил!')
            break
        
        guess = input('\nНазови букву: ')
        guesses = []
        
        if guess not in secret:
            turns -= 1
        print('\nНе угадал')
        print('\n', 'Осталось попыток: ', turns)
        if turns < 5: print ('\n  | ')
        if turns < 4: print ('  O ')
        if turns <3: print (' /|\ ')
        if turns <2: print ('  | ')
        if turns <1: print (' / \ ')
        if turns == 0: print ('\n\nЭто слово: ', secret)

ans = 'да'
while ans == 'да':
hangman()
print('Сыграем еще? (да или нет)')
ans = input()
```

Comment: еше заметил если ввести верное слово, программа так же продолжит спрашивать буквы

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Да там не один трабл. Попробуй такой список слов 
wordlist = ['ор']

Comment: Для начала исправьте табуляции, а то тут по-разному можно думать, как в реальности выглядит код.

Comment: Ну и в целом у вас там слишком много всего менять, вижу только проблемы с логикой реализации, не вижу проблем с кодом. Просто подумайте над логикой работы кода получше. Ну и код явно не дописан. `guess` потом никак не используется, можно, например, в `vowels` его добавлять.

Answer (score 1):

Мне показался код слишком сложным, я сделал свой вариант(упростил структуру и добавил _). Вроде все работает:

```
import random

def hangman():
     print('Добро пожаловать в игру Виселица')

wordlist = ['красный', 'синий', 'черный', 'белый', 'серый', 'фиолетовый', 'оранжевый', ]
secret = random.choice(wordlist)
vowels = 'аиеёоуыэюя'
turns = 5
string = len(secret)* "_"

while turns > 0:
    missed = 0
    for letter in secret:
        print(string)

        #справшиваем букву
        guess = input('\nНазови букву: ')
        guesses = []

        #проверяем букву
        if guess not in secret:
            turns -= 1
            print('\nНе угадал')
        else:
            # заменяем _ на букву
            string = string[:secret.find(guess)] + guess + string[secret.find(guess) + 1:]
            print("\nУгадал")

        # если выиграл
        if string == secret:
            print("Ты выиграл!!!")
            return
        
        print('\n', 'Осталось попыток: ', turns)
        if turns < 5: print ('\n  | ')
        if turns < 4: print ('  O ')
        if turns <3: print (' /|\ ')
        if turns <2: print ('  | ')
        if turns <1: print (' / \ ')
        if turns == 0: print ('\n\nЭто слово: ', secret)

print('Сыграем еще? (да или нет)')
ans = input()
ans = 'да'
while ans == 'да':
    hangman()
```

Comment: "Показался слишком простым", "...упростил структуры". Гениально :)

Comment: Ахахахах, сам не заметил)) Сейчас исправлю. Спасибо